# Hex literal of Int64.MinValue

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, hex

I'm trying to write Int64.MinValue (-0x8000000000000000) as a negative hexadecimal, but Visual Studio 2010 doesn't allow me because it assumes that 0x8000000000000000 must be a ulong literal, and and unsigned number cannot be negative. Is there a workaround for this? I noticed the use of the checked keyword in another thread, but it didn't solve this issue. I'd really like to use hex notation over decimal in this situation.

Interestingly, this doesn't happen with a decimal notation.

Comment: Can you multiply the result by -1 (Not sure if it'll work because you're missing the sign bit though)

Comment: I can't. Here is the exact error:
Operator '-' cannot be applied to operand of type 'ulong'

Comment: Just out of curiosity: what is the specific reason for expressing the value as a hexadecimal literal?

Comment: Hex is more sensible in a context where I use bitwise operators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This shows a few possible ways to achieve it:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Int64 minValue = -9223372036854775808;
    Int64 minValueViaHex = Int64.Parse("8000000000000000", NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
    Int64 minValueViaHexInline = unchecked((long)0x8000000000000000L);

    Console.WriteLine("Decimal match : {0}", Int64.MinValue == minValue);
    Console.WriteLine("Via Hex match : {0}", Int64.MinValue == minValueViaHex);
    Console.WriteLine("Via Hex inline: {0}", Int64.MinValue == minValueViaHexInline);
}
```

This outputs:

```
Decimal match : True
Via Hex match : True
Via Hex inline: True
```

Comment: I'm currently using decimal notation, but it just doesn't look right.

Comment: @toplel32 - Sure, out of curiosity why don't you just use `Int64.MinValue` directly as that would probably be the easiest to read?

Comment: For consistancy. I'm using other literals in the same method that represent a single bit.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
const Int64 test = unchecked((long)0x8000000000000000);
Trace.Assert(test == Int64.MinValue);
```

Or is that not what you meant?

Comment: Yes that yields the right result. What does the unchecked keyword do exactly?

Comment: @toplel32 It stops the compiler from worrying about overflow, which in this case is ok.